# How to make ubuntu one work with gnome 3?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, nautilus, gnome

I've installed gnome 3 using the following commands (using ubuntu 11.04 natty narwhal)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

My problem is that the Ubuntu one nautilus integration (right-click menu options) disappeared, although I've checked and the `ubuntuone-client-gnome` package is still installed (which is AFAIK responsible for the integration of the service).

Also, there are no more checkboxes on the shared items, no **visual** sign of synchronization activity - though the backend is working and synchronizing files put in the Ubuntu one folder as supposed to.

Any ideas how to restore the desktop integration, or I will have to wait until a new version of the client is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) for that PPA:

> This PPA is EXPERIMENTAL and MAY BREAK YOUR SYSTEM. There is no
>   downgrade process.

I'd say you might be a little stuck. I'm not an expert by any stretch here, but I'm guessing the Ubuntu One client that comes with 11.04 is not fully compatible with whatever new version of Nautilus that comes with GNOME 3. I doubt that a new version of the client will be released for 11.04 that will include GNOME 3 compatibility, so I'd say your options at this point would be:

1. maybe try writing and applying your own fixes to the Ubuntu One client source to give it GNOME 3 compatibility, or
2. reinstall your OS to return everything to a previous working state.

Comment: thanks for the answer. #2 is not really an option. however i might update to the latest U1 version, or - if I have time - tinker with the source. I will mark your answer as accepted in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Downloading the oneiric version of ubuntu-sso-client package solved the problem.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sso-client/+bug/745540/comments/32

Comment: I've installed the package linked in the comment, but no sign of improvement.